# Creating a new bibliography entry format for a clinical trial

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a document in Latex and using Jabref for my bibliography. I need to cite a clinical trial in the following format but I don't know how to make it format the entry in the right order. The rest of my bibliography is in the format 'natbib.'

The correct output is:

> Author; Author. Title. In: ClinicalTrials.gov [Internet]. Bethesda (MD): National Library of Medicine (US). 2000- [cited date]. Available from: URL of the record NLM Identifier: NCTXXXXXXXX.

The fields for the Jabref entry should be:

- Author
- Title
- Cited date
- Url

The part that says "In: ClinicalTrials.gov [Internet]. Bethesda (MD): National Library of Medicine (US). 2000-" is generic for any clinical trial entry.

I tried to make a customized entry by going to *Options → Customize Entry Types*, but when it compiles the bibliography, it formats the entry incorrectly.

I do not have a lot of experience with Latex bibliographies. Three potential solutions that I thought of but don't know how to execute are:

1. Make Latex format this specific entry without using the 'natbib' style, if possible
2. Create a new entry type in Jabref, call it Clinical, and then add to the natbib.tex file and tell it how I would like to format that entry type.
3. If there is a Latex bibliography entry that doesn't require a year, then I'm content putting the Authors and then typing the rest of it as the Title, if that is the easiest. All of the entries want a year of publication and if I try to use another type like 'article,' then (????) shows up after the author in the bibliography when I compile the document.

Comment: This could probably be achieved with [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), which has a `natbib` compatibility module, would you mind using it?

Comment: I just found out that I don't need to have the reference in my bibliography. I just needed it in the paragraph, so I typed it in. Should I leave this question here or remove it?
Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: As your question stands now, it is unlikely to be answered using only `natbib` (maybe with `biblatex`). There would need to be more information on exactly what you want(ed) to achieve. That said, if you think it might help others (leads them the right way), do not remove it.

Comment: No bibliographstyle is specified and the problem seems to have been resolved by not citing the entry. There are other examples on site on how to generate a new biblatex entry-type. I vote to close this one as unclear.